# Locally installed extension disables itself?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm testing an extension for Chrome and it's unpacked to a local directory. I installed it with the "load unpacked extension" button in settings. For some reason, after an unspecified amount of time, it just disables itself. I can go back into settings and re-enable it, but it does this *all* the time.

I'm using Ubuntu if it matters.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extension can call [`chrome.management.setEnabled(chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id"), false);`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-setEnabled) to disable it self, so if you want to stop this behavior, you could take a look at the extension code and comment out this block of code.

Comment: Could not find that code. Is there any other reason this could happen?